OPOS LDN Not Found in VS2022 (possible UAC issue?)
I know this is super esoteric but here goes:
I've just recently ported a vs2008 app to vs2022. As part of this process I'm cleaning up our various UAC issues so the application can be run properly by a user who is not admin (so the Manifest is set as AsInvoker instead of AsInstaller).
I mention this because I suspect it might be part of my problem.
OPOS drivers are not working anymore.
The app can create the OPOS control, no problem. But when trying to open the device, it is throwing an error 109, the LDN can't be found.
Oddly enough the problem seems to be SO dependent: Epson controls work great. My old NCI/Weightronix controls only work if running As Administrator. Honeywell/Metropos don't seem to work at all.
I've checked that the old 2008 code works just fine for all of these.
Again, I suspect something to do with UAC / As Administrator / VirtualStores but I'm at a loss of how to verify this hunch and what to do about it.
Thanks in advance!

It's likely that the service object stores and updates OPOS statistical information data in the registry. The OPOS of the POS vendor I used to work for was built using this mechanism. On the other hand, as written in the documentation, Epson's OPOS stores statistical information data in a file. That's probably how Epson works. In addition, for future system migrations, feature expansions, etc., you should also take into consideration the information in this article. Does OPOS works only for x86 .NET applications?

I finally figured out the answer myself so I thought I'd put this here just in case someone runs across it some day.
I got some kindly help from a Redditor that pointed me in the right direction. They suggested using Microsoft's Procmon to get some clarity on what was going on.
Sure enough, it revealed two problems:
First problem was that some of the old drivers ask for Full Access to the Registry. It was clear in Procmon that it was asking for full access and was denied (because, of course, I'm running under some proper user control now). The solution here was to set permissions on the appropriate registry key to allow USERS all access.
Second was that one of the devices was looking in the wrong location. Turns out the CLSID was generated incorrectly (weird?) and that the driver was trying to start a device type of B when it should have been a device type of B. So it was looking in the wrong place in the now read/writeable registry key. Again, that was obvious from Procmon.
